# BJT transistor overestimating Ic current

Tags: transistors, bjt

What will happen if I overestimate the saturation Ic current and thus also overestimate the saturation Ib?

My actual Ic is 10mA and I have calculated for 500mA.

Will that cause me any issues ?
I want to use the 2N2222A transistor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you really intend on using the TO-18 2N2222A? Or a TO-92 PN2222A/P2N2222A? The first you can heatsink. The second, not so much. And what do you **really** require for the collector current? And what is the circuit purpose? Finally, it is usually the circuit itself that determines the actual saturation current. So we probably need to see a schematic, first. Otherwise, not sure how to offer anything on "***issues***."